# PHP / JavaScript check SSL

Tags: php, javascript, ssl, https

Any chance to check with PHP/JavaScript is there on page any unsecured items? 
At work we here working with SSL and sometimes (rare, but still) someone of us is committing design elements with wrong path, would be good to add big red block with error, as a bonus for browser checks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand here, sometimes the path to an image is using `http://` which is causing the browser to say that some elements on the page are not secured. It's a best practice to not specify http:// nor https:// instead use the [protocol-relative url](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

You can easily check that any image on the page is using `http://` by adding this simple css rule :

```
img[src^=http\:\/\/] {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qFtVD/2/

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward.

Check:

All links, images, and script, style, link, *iframe* tags for *http://*.

Regular expressions can do the trick.

Also, you can ask people to use `://` instead. It automatically checks what protocol the page was opened through and links content correspondingly.

Comment: I've always seen it as `//`, not `://`.